# Number of zeroes of polynomials when extended to square roots

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

I'm interested in knowing about the number of real valued zeroes of polynomials extended to include square roots.

First let's call a polynomial extended to include square roots a polyquaral. A polyquaral can be recursively defined as follows :

$p=c \in \mathbb{R} | x | p_1 +p_2 | p_1*p_2 | \sqrt{p_1}$ ($x$ is a variable and $p_1$ and $p_2$ are polyquarals)

For instance this is a polyquaral : $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{x}} + \sqrt{7+x\sqrt{x}} + -0.1x - 6$

Let us define the degree of a polyquaral :

$d(c)=0 | d(x)=1 |d(p_1 +p_2) = max(d(p_1),d(p_2)) | d(p_1*p_2) = d(p_1)+d(p_2) | d(\sqrt{p_1}) = d(p_1)/2$

Next I would like to informally introduce a notion called the square root nesting, noted $i$, of a polyquaral. Which should correspond to the highest number of nested square roots in a polyquaral. For example a term like $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{x}}$ has two nested square roots.

$i(c)=0 | i(x)=0 |i(p_1 +p_2) = max(i(p_1),i(p_2)) | i(p_1*p_2) = max(i(p_1),i(p_2)) | i(\sqrt{p_1}) = i(p_1)+1$

This definition is informal as the rule for multiplication is false in general (if you multiply $\sqrt{x}$ by itself you get $x$ and reduce the amount of nested square rooting), but making it formal would take too much time at this point.

I'm interested in knowing what is the number of zeroes (over $\mathbb{R}$ of a polyquaral $p$ depending on the degree of $p$, and the number of nested squareroots. (maybe those are not the relevant values to answer this question, in which case feel free to modify them). There is a trivial upperbound where you just solve $p=O$ by repeatedly moving the most "square-root nested" term to the right and squaring both sides. At the end you end up with a polynomial equation of a certain (large) degree. This degree grows **at least** in $d*2^{i}$ where $d$ is the highest degree appearing in $p$ and $i$ is the nesting of square roots. In actuality in grows even faster cause if you have $n$ terms with the same amount of nested square roots you need to repeat the aforementionned algorithm at least $n$ times it seems to get rid of all the squareroots.

But in reality i would guess that the amount of zeroes of a polyquaral is much lower than this, maybe affine in the degree of the polyquaral. Has there been any study on this ? If one could prove an upperbound of $d*2^{i}$ on the number of zeroes it would actually suffice for what I need.

A other way to look at this problem might be as an analytic one, by computing polyquarals derivative, but i didn't get very far that way.

Comment: The rule $d(p_1 + p_2) = \max(d(p_1), d(p_2))$ is not even true for polynomials. A similar issue exists for $i(p_1+p_2)$.

Comment: Yes you are right, i guess just take the degree of the canonical representation (which would have to be defined)

Comment: What is the definition of this notation?  $\mathbb{R} | x | p_1 +p_2 | p_1*p_2 | \sqrt{p_1}$

Comment: It's just a simple way of describing a polyquaral. This notation is used in computer science which is my background. It read as follows : "a polyquaral is either a real number OR a variable x OR the addition of two polyquaral OR the multiplication of two polyquaral OR the square root of a polyquaral. And you recursively build the set of all polyquarals. A polyquaral is just a function composed of only addition ,multiplication, and square rooting (as many times as you want) of constants or variables.

Answer (score 2):

There are examples with lots of zeros.

First, note that $p(x) = x - \sqrt{x^2}$ has an uncountable number of zeros. However, we can consider this to be a degenerate case: this can happen only if we get the identically zero polynomial after clearing all of the square roots.

In the next examples I will write $|x|$ instead of $\sqrt{x^2}$ for convenience; they are the same function for real $x$.

Let's look at the family of examples $q_n(x)$ that extend the following pattern in the natural way:
$$q_3(x) = \left|\left|\left|x-2^3\right| - 2^2\right| - 2^1\right| -2^0.$$
The function $q_n(x)$ has $2^n$ zeros (at the odd integers between $0$ and $2^{n+1}$). This example achieves the full number of zeros possible, as the polynomial resulting from eliminating the square roots has degree $2^n$.

Now consider the family of examples
$$p_n(x) = -(2n-1) + \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}(-1)^{k+1} \left|x-2k\right|.$$
Here $i(p_n) = 1$ and $d(p_n) = 1$, yet $p_n(x)$ has $2n$ zeros (at the odd integers between $0$ and $4n$). So there can be no upper bound that depends only on $i(p)$ and $d(p)$.

(As a side note, I was surprised to discover that I had come up with the same example twice: $q_n(x)$ is the exact same function as $p_{2^{n-1}}(x)$!)

If you don't like the fact that $q_n(x)$ and $p_n(x)$ are not differentiable, we can perturb these functions slightly to make them infinitely differentiable on the real line: just replace $|x|$ with $\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon}$ for a sufficiently small positive $\epsilon$.

Finally, an explicit upper bound for the number of zeros of $p(x)$ is given by
$$d(p)\cdot 2^{j(p)}$$
where $d(p)$ is the (possibly fractional) degree of $p$ as you have defined it, and $j(p)$ is the number of distinct square roots that appear in $p$.

This can be derived as follows: multiply $p(x)$ by all of its conjugates, where each conjugate is obtained by replacing each distinct square root in $p$ with either its positive or negative version. This results in a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of degree at most $d(p) \cdot 2^{j(p)}$.

One way to interpret this result is that if the signs of the square roots are chosen independently at random, the expected value of the number of zeros is at most $d(p)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the two provided examples. For square root simplification you have a nice solution, however the bound is huge. I still supect the actual bound should be lower even though you may reach it in some cases(i.e.you can find a quantity lower than $j(p)$, like $i(p)$ maybe such that there are at most $d*2^i$ zeroes,  $i$ is always lower or equal to $j$ and as such it's a better bound). I would like to know if this quantity $j(p)$ is indeed the best we can do (i don't know how to formulate it mathematically though)

Comment: A problem I have is that when we add two polyquarals, $j$ is doubled but I highly doubt the number of zeroes should be squared. If you have an example where that is the case I'm highly interested.

Comment: It does seem plausible that the number of possible zeros is additive rather than multiplicative when taking sums. This claim is at least true for nested absolute value expressions that are piecewise linear, such as the two examples that I gave. I'll see if I can come up with a more general argument.